# Typescript - function cannot return undefined

Tags: typescript

I defined this function:

```
const getOrDefault = <T>(a: T, b: T): T => (a != null ? a : b)
```

what's the correct way to express `a` might be `null/undefined` but `b` cannot, and the function always return a valid value?

As of now it returns `undefined | T`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the conditional type `Exclude` to exclude from `T` `null` or `undefined`:

```
const getOrDefault = <T>(a: T, b: Exclude<T, null | undefined>): Exclude<T, null | undefined> => (a !== null ? a : b) as Exclude<T, null | undefined> 

declare let a: string | null
getOrDefault(a, null) // error
getOrDefault(a, undefined) // error
getOrDefault(a, "") // ok

declare let b: string | undefined
getOrDefault(b, null) // error
getOrDefault(b, undefined) // error
getOrDefault(b, "") // ok

declare let c: string;
getOrDefault(c, null) // error
getOrDefault(c, undefined) // error
getOrDefault(c, "") // ok
```

Comment: That's interesting. Didn't even know Exclude existed

Comment: Btw, I created an alias `type NotNull<T> = Exclude<T, null | undefined>`

Comment: Hey, I discovered there is a built-in type `NonNullable`